# Haproxy: how to configure backend to talk with a https server?

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy

We have in our LAN a nginx server configured in https.

In front, we have Haproxy with SSL and we need to establish a connection SSL from backend to nginx server. Is it possible to do this?

Client -> Haproxy:SSL -> SSL:Nginx

```
backend pkiservices
    mode http
    option httplog
    option forwardfor
    server pki pkiservices.example.com:443
```

With this configuration, Nginx return an erreur 400 (The plain HTTP request was sent to https port).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that all you wanted to know? Be precise with your questions, state the problem you had when you tried it, show logs, etc.

Comment: Yes and I want to know how to do force Haproxy to make a ssl request. So, thanks to Longneck, the linked thread and the responses helped me. Thanks!